# Scss not loading in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Up until yesterday styles.scss loaded fine but today when I make new changes to styles.css.scss they do not load (in development).

Rake assets: clean works but I have to do that every time to change css.

My application.css looks like this (hasn't changed):

```
 /*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I know this isn't a lot of information but i'm not sure what else to add.

**EDIT**

OK so i got it to work by adding this to to environments/development.rb:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

This was not there before and everything was working so any idea why i needed to add it today?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, application.css.scss starts with a comment, which is missing!

```
/*
```

I don't believe it was compiling and wash giving an error in the console/log file.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that but it's there.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this was turned off? `config.assets.debug = true`

Comment: No not that either. Weird huh.